# Open window From Microsoft Edge to IE

Tags: c#-4.0, microsoft-edge

As I been researching Microsoft Edge doesn't support PDF Viewing. So they have that button to open in IE. I wondering if anyone know how to use the button in C# code to open a pop up in IE from Edge?

Comment: PDF support is built into Edge natively. If you are encountering issues with Edge's PDF support, please consider contacting the team at [@msedgedev](https://twitter.com/msedgedev) on Twitter. Besides this, there is no supported method for invoking Internet Explorer from Microsoft Edge.

Comment: The issue I having is that I got a web site that uses Report Viewer. It loads the rdlc file to display the report. But in edge it continue to load my report and not display it in PDF format. it will show that the PDF files as been downloaded you can open it but you can show the PDF in the web page!!!

Comment: Can you point me to an example URL that shows the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? I'm not sure it would work for a web app.

```
Process reportInIE = Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", "http://YOUR_SERVER_NAME/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?REPORT_LOCATION&rs:Command=Render&rs:format=PDF&PARAM_ONE=1");
```